# gtk tree view. Handle both single and double click

Tags: signals, gtk3

According to the GTK+3 [reference site](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#GtkTreeView-row-activated):

> The "row-activated" signal is emitted when the method
>   gtk_tree_view_row_activated() is called, when the user double clicks a
>   treeview row with the "activate-on-single-click" property set to
>   FALSE, or when the user single clicks a row when the
>   "activate-on-single-click" property set to TRUE. It is also emitted
>   when a non-editable row is selected and one of the keys: Space,
>   Shift+Space, Return or Enter is pressed.

Is there really no way to deal with both single and double click? For example, single click does an action, double click another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use parent signals, in this case GtkWidget's signal "button-press-event", with the event of GDK_BUTTON_PRESS doing something and GDK_2BUTTON_PRESS doing other.
Little note: you have grab the GtkTreeViewSelection on which row you need.

Answer (score 2):

This was meant to be a comment under luciomrx answer, but is to long. In my case `button-press-event` didn't worked, because its handler gets fired before selection is even performed. So I simply switched to `button-release-event` and from there I checked for selection using `gtk_tree_selection_get_selected` (works only for "single" and "browse" selection modes). But in my case I wanted to show some window on double click, and simply change descriptions when user selects a row (i.e. when row gets highlighted). I think this is common scenario. And the drawback of aforementioned implementation is that user can change selection using keyboard, so my labels were left unchanged. So I used `GtkTreeSelection` "changed" signal instead (obtain it using `gtk_tree_view_get_selection` method).